# Create an array from similarly named IDs

Tags: jquery

I have a group of IDs with similar names (ex: div1, div2, div3) that are all going to perform the same function. Is there an easy way in jQuery to create an array by calling the prefix of the id ("div")?

Comment: the answer to that depends on the nature of those ids. Are they dynamically generated or static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [attribute selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith) to test the start of the ID attribute value:

```
[id^=div]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a filter selector that gets all divs where the id starts with "div" like this:

```
 $("div[id^='div']")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the id values of your divs are div1, div2, div3.

```
$("div[id^=div]")
```

This doesn't work anymore:

```
$('div#div\\S*')
```